# ASP.NET Entity Framework and FileWatcher Events

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, events

I have a question regarding the EF in our ASP.NET Web Application. For our specific use-case we have to listen to a directory for added XML files. This works correctly using `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`. Everything is wrapped within a class, which looks like this.

```
namespace Server.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using Server.Events;

    public class FileWatcher
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     The watcher which listens to the directory. This variable has to be a property to ensure, that it is not destroyed
        ///     after its local lifecycle.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly FileSystemWatcher watcher;

        public FileWatcher(string directory)
        {
            this.watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
                               {
                                   Path = directory,
                                   NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                                                                           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                                                           | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size
                                                                           | NotifyFilters.Security,
                                   Filter = "*.xml",
                               };

            this.watcher.Created += this.OnCreate;
            this.watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     The event, which is fired when a new XML file is found.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<NewFileEventArgs> NewXmlFile;

        /// <summary>
        ///     The function which gets called by the system watcher as soon as a new XML file is found.
        ///     Fetches the file and waits until it is completely loaded. The problem is, that the file watcher immediately
        ///     triggers, as soon as the file is created. Big files therefore might run into some issues without waiting.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnCreate(object source, FileSystemEventArgs args)
        {
            var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var fileChecker = new FileChecker(args.FullPath);
            new Timer(fileChecker.CheckStatus, autoEvent, 1000, 500);

            autoEvent.WaitOne();

            this.NewXmlFile?.Invoke(this, new NewFileEventArgs(args.FullPath));
        }
    }
}
```

After subscribing to the event `NewXmlFile`, the file should be passed down to a custom XML data extractor, which basically fetches the data and inserts the data into our database with the help of the EF. (We already have Database Initializers that do this exact thing on program startup once. But in this case it should automatically run this exact same process again, as soon as a new file is received within the said directory).

Within my `Program.cs` I subscribe to the `NewXmlFile` event like this.

```
fileWatcher = new FileWatcher("C:/myPath");
fileWatcher.NewXmlFile += OnNewFile;
```

Where the `Program::OnNewFile` looks like this:

```
private static void OnNewFile(object sender, NewFileEventArgs args)
{
    //INJECT DEPENDENCIES HERE
    var xmlDataImport = new XmlDataImport();

    var success = xmlDataImport.Import(args.FilePath).Result;
    
    if (success)
    {
        File.Delete(args.FilePath);
    }
}
```

As seen in the comment, I need to pass down my dependencies within the XmlDataImport class. Anyways, I have no idea how to do so. Since I always get the exception `Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IMyService'`.

Things that I tried so far:

- Inject the `IServiceProvider` into my `Program.cs`, when I create the Filewatcher `new FileWatcher(serviceProvider, path)`, store it within a private property and pass it down as a custom EventArgs property when I trigger the `NewXmlFile` event. I then fetch the `IServiceProvider` from the passed EventArgs and inject them manually into the constructor of `XmlDataImport(args.provider)` in the `Program::OnNewFile` method.
- Make the `IServiceProvider` static within `Program.cs` and manually inject it into    `XmlDataImport(provider)` in the `Program::OnNewFile` method.

Anyways, it totally makes sense that the object is already disposed. But within the documentation I did not find a way to get it to work. Maybe someone ran into a similar issue and can help. Thanks!

Comment: it really depends on the lifetime of your `FileWatcher`, looks like the whole picture is not shown. You may rely on `singleton services` if possible. `Scoped services` will live in a scope which may be out of your control (such as in the scope of a request processing pipeline).

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for your reply! I did not state it in my original answer, but the FileWatcher is static within `Program.cs`. As I said, the whole directory observation stuff works as intended, therefore I highly doubt that it has to do with the FileWatcher itself (otherwise the event wouldn't trigger). I gonna have a read on singleton and scoped services for now. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to @King King. For anyone having a similar problem:

You have to create a new HostedService and add it to your `Startup.cs`.

```cs
this.services.AddHostedService<FileImportTask>();
```

Afterwards, your Hosted Service can import the `IServiceProvider` in its constructor. Within my specific use case i can directly bind to the event I am firing within the `StartAsync` method (make sure you also unsubscribe from it). Within the event method I can then create a new scope, from which I now have access to all the services.

```cs
    public class FileImportTask: IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        private readonly ILogger<FileImportTask> logger;
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        private FileWatcher fileWatcher;

        public FileImportTask(ILogger<FileImportTask> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.configuration = configuration;
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            var path = this.configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:XmlPath");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            this.fileWatcher = new FileWatcher(path);
            this.fileWatcher.NewXmlFile += this.OnNewFile;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            this.fileWatcher.NewXmlFile -= this.OnNewFile;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void OnNewFile(object sender, NewFileEventArgs args)
        {
            using (var scope = this.serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var myService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
                //USE SERVICE HERE!
            }
        }
    }
```